# github API; returning an array of tags

Tags: github

I was wondering if the following is possible -- and how to do it.

Can I somehow use the github API to return an array of tags for an existing repository?

I have a file that I periodically "commit" with version tags. So I'd like to be able to call github and return something like:

```
$tags = $tags('v1.0', 'v1.1', 'v2.0', 'v2.1')
```

Or maybe even an associative array that includes both the tag and the date.

But anyway, I'd like to then call to Github and return this list. Then I can allow the user to select the version of they would like to see using the following github url:

```
https://raw.github.com/<username>/<projectname>/<tagname>/<filepath>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [GitHub V3 API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/) and parse the result to build your array:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitolite/git/refs/tags|grep "\"refs"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

"ref": "refs/tags/nonstd-path-for-00", 6:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.50", 1
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.55",62
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.60",
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.65",
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.70",62
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.80",
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.85",0:
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.90",1
"ref": "refs/tags/v0.95",0:
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.0",-:
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.0rc1",-
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.1",
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.2",
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.3",
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.4",
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.4.1",
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.4.2",
"ref": "refs/tags/v1.5",
```