# Get GitHub tags into PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, github-api

Basically i need to get the tags for a given repo and place the result in a php array

I've seen [github API; returning an array of tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066904/github-api-returning-an-array-of-tags) but i have no experience with cURL.

I think the url would be https://api.github.com/repos/joshf/MYREPO/git/refs/tag but i'm not sure how to get the answer into an array

I found a guide for v2 of the GitHub API but not for v3

Any help would be appreciated

EDIT:

```
<?php


$url = "https://api.github.com/repos/joshf/Burden/git/refs/tags";
$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "test");
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $r;

$response_array = json_decode($r, true);
echo $response_array->{"ref"};

?>
```

Gives me

```
[{"ref":"refs/tags/1.2","url":"https://api.github.com/repos/joshf/Burden/git/refs/tags/1.2","object":{"sha":"d04eabe44b52e65ca2e1c1eaaca4321195d85001","type":"tag","url":"https://api.github.com/repos/joshf/Burden/git/tags/d04eabe44b52e65ca2e1c1eaaca4321195d85001"}},{"ref":"refs/tags/1.3","url":"https://api.github.com/repos/joshf/Burden/git/refs/tags/1.3","object":{"sha":"74d40e3f89717cbadc11e23e8ab4350d85deb015","type":"tag","url":"https://api.github.com/repos/joshf/Burden/git/tags/74d40e3f89717cbadc11e23e8ab4350d85deb015"}}]
```

All i want is the 1.2 and 1.3 bit of the tags

Comment: What did you try so far? You might want to start with [**`curl documentation`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)

Comment: I tried [this](http://davidwalsh.name/github-markdown)

Comment: Alright so improve your question, include your code and tell us where you find problems

Comment: I understand the curl stuff i think, its just getting the result as an array, everything i've seen says about json

Comment: You can manage to get data from array by looping in it with a foreach

Comment: `json_decode` is what you're looking for, second parameter as TRUE to get as an associative array.

Comment: Have updated my code to show new problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode your response to an associated array  with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function, passing association as `true`

```
 $resonse_array = json_decode($content, true);
```